# How to add a guest public ssh key for remote access?

Tags: macos, ssh

I need to add a developers public ssh key to my user account so that he can access my console and help debug a node.JS issue. Any suggestions on where to start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have them give you their public key, e. g. `id_rsa.pub`.  Add that to the end of your `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` file (e.g. by running `cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` in Terminal).

Comment: is that it. So just save the key below my public key file and all is good?

Comment: Yep, that's it; once you've done they (presuming you have the SSH server running and so forth), your friend should be albe to `ssh yourusername@host.example.com` (or use your IP address which you can see [here](http://www.ipchicken.com)).

Comment: reminder, he'll have access to your account and all the rights associated with it.

Comment: Great. Here is a gap online on this issue. Great answers.

Comment: *there is a gap